# How to view my GPU's base frequency and memory type using command prompt?

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe, gpu

I tried using wmic path win32_VideoController command but it is not showing the base frequency and memory type.

Comment: See if anything here helps>>>>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38158066/graphics-memory-info-with-cmd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SuperUser!

I've found a couple of possible solutions so far. One involves using a well-known tool, [GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) which has a command-line option to dump specifications to a file, which you could then read in. Apparently it's in XML, though, so you may have to do some extra work to find what you're looking for.

Another, possibly simpler, option is [Overdrive5](https://github.com/BackupGGCode/overdrive5). I haven't tested it myself, but the documentation looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **wmic** in CMD

```
wmic PATH Win32_VideoController
```

If you want to be selected, you can use this code.

```
wmic PATH Win32_VideoController get name
```

**Result**

**Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).